# Super key stuck on 20.04

Tags: gnome, keyboard, debugging

I was recently editing a gnome extension when my computer started acting like the super key is constantly pressed. I can only execute super shortcuts with the keyboard. In addition, all shortcut options in settings now read as disabled. Possible solutions I’ve tried:

- pressing <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>
- changing regional keyboard type
- swapping physical keyboards
- disabling and uninstalling all gnome extensions
- reinstalling gnome-shell
- resetting `dconf` shortcuts
- solutions from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60007/how-to-force-release-of-a-keyboard-modifiers (though from the login screen. Suggestions as to how to execute terminal commands without pressing enter would be helpful!)

Any help would be much appreciated, as my laptop is currently unusable.
Thanks a lot!